# The for loop for an array of 4 elements does not work

Tags: arrays, for-loop, element

I am trying to make the following for loop that has to return the elements from my vAgarch array. However, instead of the elements: 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05 I get zeros:

```
vAgarch= [0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
vAgarch= np.array(vAgarch)

iN= vAgarch.shape[0]
vA= np.zeros(iN)
a=0
for i in range(iN):
    vAgarch[i]= vA[a]
    a= a+1

 print(vA)
```

Anyone who can help me with the for loop? I need to get an array with each element of vAgarch.
Thanks!

Comment: If i type iN, I get 4. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Nothing in the loop changes `vA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken the sides in the assignment, the code

```
vAgarch[i] = vA[a]
```

should be:

```
vA[a] = vAgarch[i]
```

Note: You don't need additional counter `a`, you can see that it is the same as `i` always, so you can use `i` as index in both arrays.

### Update

```
vAgarch= [0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]

iN= vAgarch.shape[0]
vA= np.zeros(iN)

for i in range(iN):
    vA[i] = np.fabs(vAgarch[i])
```

Comment: You are talking about an array of floats. Check the update.

Comment: Great thank you very much!! However, I have one more question: the elements are now structured in an array, but I want to have them out of an array. So just like single floats. I could do this by hand for each element: dA1garch= np.fabs(vAgarch[0], dA1garch= np.fabs(vAgarch[1]). But if I have 40 elements for example, this is a lot work. Do you know if this can be put in a for loop as well and how?

Comment: In the end, I want to create an array called vP that consist of dA, dB and all the elements (in float form) of vA. Since dA and dB are both floats, I cannot create an array with dA and dB and then add the array vA. So I thought create all floats and then put them into an list. Then convert that list into an array.. but maybe there is an easier way

Comment: You can do that, yes

Comment: Do you know how? And if yes, could you help me with that? I have been trying do this for a day but it won't work..

Comment: This should be another question, otherwise the risk is that this answer becomes out of context. Accept this one if it helped you solve the initial problem and then write a new question about the other issue.